# Json Query: Stopped working

Tags: c#, json, httprequest

I made this little program one month ago:

```
            input = "20032608";
            string url = "http://ion.inapi.cl:8080/Patente/ConsultaAvanzadaPatentes.aspx/GetCaratula";
            Uri uri = new Uri(url);
            HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url) as System.Net.HttpWebRequest;

            request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            request.Method = "POST";
            var postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Sol_Nro = input, Ori = 1 });
            var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;

            using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

            request.Timeout = System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite;

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

However, some day it stopped working, returning a 500 internal server error. This is the source code of the JS:

http://ion.inapi.cl:8080/Patente/js/ConsultaAvanzadaPatentes.js

I am not sure if the problem has something to do with the new parameter 'Ori'.

I tried modifying the postdata to:

```
var postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Sol_Nro = input, Ori = 1 });
```

However, now I get a 500 internal server error.
Any ideas?

This is the method GetCaratula. I'll post only the relevant part:

```
function getCaratula(sol_nro, ori) {
    var params = new Object();
    params.Sol_Nro = sol_nro;
    params.Ori = ori;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "ConsultaAvanzadaPatentes.aspx/GetCaratula",
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data, textStatus) {
            if (textStatus == "success") {
                var obj = $.parseJSON(data.d);

                if (obj.ErrorMessage == null) {

....

        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert($.parseJSON(request.responseText).Message);
        }
    });    
}
```

Comment: Post the relevant code **in** the question, not just linked. Links rot, and people shouldn't have to follow random links to help you. See the [help] for details.

Comment: If you didn't change the client side code it suggests the error started to occur on the server side.  500 means server error.

Comment: Can you post `GetCaratula` method?

Comment: I didn't change the client side code, but you can perform the query in the webpage without problems. It seems something is blocking the program from retrieving the response.

Comment: Not js version of `GetCaratula` but server side method, it should be in the `ConsultaAvanzadaPatentes.aspx.cs` file.

Comment: There is no such file or at least is not visible by the browser.

Comment: @user3472931 you can browse the page at, http://ion.inapi.cl:8080/Patente/ConsultaAvanzadaPatentes.aspx/GetCaratula

Comment: P.K. In fact, the page is http://ion.inapi.cl:8080/Patente/ConsultaAvanzadaPatentes.aspx